# Perl Script to mark radio button and execute javascript button

Tags: javascript, perl

I would like to create a perl script that marks a radio box and clicks the vote button. This is for a online poll where you vote for a local fire department, the top 5 departments get a grant to help buy new supplies. They have it set up so that you can vote 1 time every 5 minutes. I am having trouble getting the javascript button to execute. I have spent hours doing research but I cant find a clear solution.

So far I have:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );

$mech->get( "http://spenglerco.com/everyday-heroes-fund/" );
$mech->set_fields('yop-poll-li-answer-2_yp52e5b2ce31180' => '32');
```

I realize Mechanize may not be ideal to execute javascript but i have got the farthest with it so far.

Thank You for your help

Answer (score 1):

WWW::Mechanize does not execute JavaScript.  It is not a web browser.  It is a simple HTTP client with tools to access the DOM.  If you want a Perl Module that has the full functionality of a web browser I think you're pretty much out of luck (I could be wrong).  I did hear once about someone makeing a version of mechanize that used FireFox behind the scenes, but I don't think that got off the ground.

I'd suggest figuring out what URL the javascript ends up calling, and just call that URL directly.

Answer (score 1):

You might use the headless Webkit browser phantomjs either directly (e.g. script your solution with javascript) or through perl http://blogs.perl.org/users/robhammond/2013/02/web-scraping-with-perl-phantomjs.html.